# Nginx Not apply add_header directives to WordPress JS, CSS, images resource files URL's header

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

In my Nginx setup, I used the following add header configurations. But when I check my site JS and CSS resources header, it's not added these add_header configurations to HTTP header. What's missing in my configuration? When I check home page and post pages URL's header, I can see the following `add_header` configurations.

```
  add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=3600, proxy-revalidate";
  add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
  add_header Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin;
  add_header X-DNS-Prefetch-Control On;
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
  add_header Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=(), camera=(), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), usb=()";
```

This is my server block file. Above `add_header` configurations are saved on `include vhost.d/*.conf`; directory.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name site.com www.site.com;

    # WebinolySSLstart
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/chain.pem;
    # WebinolySSLend    
    access_log on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.com.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.com.access.log;
    
    root /var/www/site.com/htdocs;
    
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    include common/auth.conf;
    
    # WebinolyCustom
    
    #fast-cgi cache
    include cachekeys/site.conf;
    
    # WebinolyCustomEnd
    
    include common/wpfc.conf;
    include common/wpcommon.conf;
    include common/locations.conf;
    include common/headers-http.conf;
    include common/headers-https.conf;
    include common/headers-html.conf;
    include common/yoast-sitemap.conf;
    include /var/www/site.com/*-nginx.conf;
    
    #my custom configurations.
    include custom/sql-attack.conf;
    include vhost.d/*.conf; 
    
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify any other `add_header` statements probably embedded within `location` blocks.

Comment: If there's only single add_header statement in location block, then Nginx ignore all other server block add_header statements?

Comment: Yes, [as documented](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header).

Comment: @RichardSmith I managed to fix this issue. In my situation, `mod_pagespeed` cause this issue. After Added included `add_header` to `mod_pagespeed` everything fixed.